# Get The Element "Text" from xml in selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, testautomationfx

I have the follwing nodes in XML :

```
<div class="publishing" xpath="1">
Par Aymen Test - aymen.test@test.fr
<br>
<time datetime="2022-10-11T16:01:20+02:00">Publié le 11/10/2022 à 16h01</time>
</div>
```

I want to get the text element following the class "publishing"
Knowing that I can't use the content of text because it changes.

I tried with :

```
WebElement MyText = driver.findElement(By.xpath ("//div[@class='publishing']"));
System.out.println(MyText.getText());
```

But I get :

```
Par Aymen Test - aymen.test@test.fr
Publié le 11/10/2022 à 16h01
```

I need just :

```
Par Aymen Test - aymen.test@test.fr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the total text and then remove from it the text content of child elements.
This should work:

```java
WebElement parentEl = driver.findElement(By.xpath ("//div[@class='publishing']"));
String totaltext = parentEl.getText();
List<WebElement> children = parentEl.findElement(By.xpath (".//*"));
for(WebElement child : children){
    totaltext = totaltext.replace(child.getText(), "");
}
System.out.println(totaltext);
```